# Openseadragon : weird selection rotation when rotating canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, openseadragon

I am currently working on a viewer using OpenSeadragon, and the Picturae selection plugin for adding a cropping tool.

Selection is working fine, but when I rotate the image, rotation of selection is acting weird : it rotate around the bottom left corner, instead of the center of selection.

[I made a video of the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Z9c.jpg) : normal behavior of selection rotation when image is straight, and weird behavior when image is rotated.

The desired effect is to rotate around the center of selection...

I use the following code to initialize selection :

```
var selection = viewer.selection({
  element:                 null, // html element to use for overlay
  showSelectionControl:    true, // show button to toggle selection mode
  toggleButton:            null, // dom element to use as toggle button
  showConfirmDenyButtons:  true,
  styleConfirmDenyButtons: true,
  returnPixelCoordinates:  true,
  keyboardShortcut:        'c', // key to toggle selection mode
  rect:                    null, // initial selection as an OpenSeadragon.SelectionRect object
  startRotated:            false, // alternative method for drawing the selection; useful for rotated crops
  startRotatedHeight:      0.1, // only used if startRotated=true; value is relative to image height
  restrictToImage:         true, // true = do not allow any part of the selection to be outside the image
  onSelection:             function(rect) { viewer_crop_download(rect); },
  cancel : function(){ viewer_crop_disable(); },
  prefixUrl:     PREFIX_URL,
  navImages:
  {
    selection: {
     REST:   'selection_rest.png',
     GROUP:  'selection_grouphover.png',
     HOVER:  'selection_hover.png',
     DOWN:   'selection_pressed.png'
    },
    selectionConfirm: {
     REST:   'selection_confirm_rest.png',
     GROUP:  'selection_confirm_grouphover.png',
     HOVER:  'selection_confirm_hover.png',
     DOWN:   'selection_confirm_pressed.png'
    },
    selectionCancel: {
     REST:   'selection_cancel_rest.png',
     GROUP:  'selection_cancel_grouphover.png',
     HOVER:  'selection_cancel_hover.png',
     DOWN:   'selection_cancel_pressed.png'
    },
  }
});
```

OpenSeadragon : https://openseadragon.github.io

Picturae selection plugin : https://picturae.github.io/openseadragonselection/

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug with the selection plugin. Some discussion here: https://github.com/picturae/openseadragonselection/issues/1

Comment: Indeed, so I will implement a fix by myself.

Comment: Sounds good. Please share the fix if you can!